# Unity Particle system: Change Emitter Velocity with Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, particle-system

I have a particle system connected with an object that it follows. The Emitter Velocity is here set on Rigidbody. What I want is to have the particle system follow the object, as it does, but when detecting a touch input the particles are to follow the touch input, changing the Emitter Velocity to Transform. When running the code that I attached, there are two compiler errors that I have tried and failed to fix. Would appreciate someone taking a look at it.

- The 'Particle System' does not contain a definition for
  'emitterVelocity' and no accessible extension method
  'emitterVelocity' accepting a first argument of type 'ParticleSystem'
  could be found. line 28.
- 'Transform' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.
  line 28.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DragFingerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 touchPosition;
    private ParticleSystem ps;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private float moveSpeed = 10f;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0;
            direction = (touchPosition - transform.position);
            ps.emitterVelocity = Transform;
            ps.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y) * moveSpeed;

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                ps.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when trying to access the `Transform` to which a Unity component is attached, you want to use `transform` (note lowercase "t" vs. uppercase). Switch `Transform` to `transform` or `this.transform`.

`transform` is a property that all `MonoBehaviours` have that gives the same value as calling `this.GetComponent<Transform>()`. By contrast, `Transform` is the type `UnityEngine.Transform`, which is to say there exists a class with that name.

Second, in regards to setting the emitter, you can set the `emitterVelocityMode` (labelled as "Emitter Velocity") in the [particle system's `main` component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-main.html). The values for `emitterVelocityMode` are [an enum named "ParticleSystemEmitterVelocityMode"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystemEmitterVelocityMode.html).

You can say:

```
var ps_main = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main;
ps_main.emitterVelocityMode = ParticleSystemEmitterVelocityMode.Transform;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Here is a screenshot from the inspector: https://imgur.com/a/KLgSK5F

Comment: The answer has been updated accordingly. Hope it helps.